# How can I select the "Sort By" element through Selenium Webdriver Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I was trying to automate one task using Selenium Webdriver with Python 2.7.The task goes as follows:
1. Open "https://www.flipkart.com".
2. Search for 'laptop'.
3. Hit search button.
4. Whatever is the answer of the search query, sort them "By Popularity" using the sort button.

Code

```
from selenium import webdriver

url="https://www.flipkart.com"
xpaths={'submitButton' :   "//button[@type='submit']",
    'searchBox' : "//input[@type='text']"}

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maxmimize_window()

driver.get(url)

#to search for laptops
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['searchBox']).clear()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['searchBox']).send_keys('laptop')
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['submitButton']).click()

#to sort them by popularity
driver.find_element_by_xpath("////*[@id='container']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/section/ul/li[2]").click()
```

The last statement throws an error:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression ////*[@id='container']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/section/ul/li[2] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '////*[@id='container']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/section/ul/li[2]' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=53.0.2785.143)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)
```

Given I copied the xpath for that particular element "Sort By - Popularity" using the Chrome developer tools(ctrl+shift+I).

And also, it highlights the same element when I try to search for that xpath in the console window of developer tools.

What's wrong with the xpath?
Help!

Comment: 'not a valid XPath expression' --> try "//*..." instead of "////*..."

Answer (score 1):

As far as syntax error goes replace `////` with `//` in your xpath

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*@id='container']/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/section/ul/li[2]").click()`

This will resolve your syntax error and will do the required job
Though In my opinion a better XPATH would be
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[text()='Popularity']").click()`

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
url="https://www.flipkart.com"
xpaths={'submitButton' :   "//button[@type='submit']",
    'searchBox' : "//input[@type='text']"}

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
#   driver.maxmimize_window()

driver.get(url)

#to search for laptops
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['searchBox']).clear()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['searchBox']).send_keys('laptop')
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['submitButton']).click()

#to sort them by popularity
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[text()='Popularity']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try with this css selector too:

```
#container > div > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2)  > div > div:nth-child(2)  > div:nth-child(2)  > div > section > ul > li:nth-child(2)
```

To me, cssSelector is better than xpath for browser compatibility too.